# calling activity

Tags: android

i am new to android development and i am confused about activities (not even sure if they are called activities lol)
how would i go about starting another activity from within one?

```
public void work(View v) {
     //does quite a bit of stuff in here
     //then goes back to csend() to check if this needs to be repeated
}

public void csend(View view) {  
     if (i  < x){   
         //does a little bit of stuff here
     work(); //i need to make this run the other code   
     }
}
```

also, what does the (View view) mean, could someone give me a link to a tutorial explaining the different parts to android code?

thanks
Edit: thanks for the quick response, i'll go read up on everything

Comment: [d.android.com](http://developer.android.com/index.html) is the ultimate destination.

Comment: Read this official docs http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: I would look through the android developer docs.

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent showContent = new Intent(this, ActivityName.class);
startActivity(showContent);
```

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/03/tutorial-how-to-start-a-new-activity/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use,

```
startActivity(new Intent(YourClassName.this, SecondActivity.class));
```